# Angular event from jQuery code

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using an Angular 5 theme which has some widgets created with jQuery. I need to add Angular events (click) on the elements which are generated from jQuery. This is a part of the jQuery code which generates a table:

```
template: function(data) {
            var dropup = (data.getDatatable().getPageSize() -
                data.getIndex()) <=
            4 ? 'dropup' : '';

            return '\
                <div class="dropdown ' + dropup + '">\
                    <a href="#" class="btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" data-toggle="dropdown">\
                        <i class="la la-ellipsis-h"></i>\
                    </a>\
                    <span id="editDetails" (click)="editDetails(1)" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" title="Edit details">\
                       <i class="la la-edit"></i>\
                    </span>\';
```

Can you please advise how to force Angular to work here? I need to go to the 'Edit' page when clicking on the "editDetails" button, so the page change should be done from the Anuglar component.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not possible if you add elements by jQuery or inner html. You have to create a template in a angular component and add event there. Apply jQuery after view creation. Then it is possible. Angular not support directly manipulation of Dom and event bindings.

Comment: @mukundpatel - thanks!